# Cannot fix PDOException::(“could not find driver”) on Laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Here's a list of stuff I've done in order to attempt to fix the issue:

I'm on Windows 7 and using MAMP. My PHP version is 7.3.7.

The full error I'm getting is:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lol and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e

    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Backend\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:31

  2   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Backend\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:27

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Used `phpinfo()` on one of the pages served by the server in order to determine PHP version and location of `php.ini` file. My PHP version is 7.3.7 and my `php.ini` file is located at `C:\MAMP\conf\php7.3.7\php.ini`. These 3 lines are uncommented in that file:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Used get_loaded_extensions on one of the pages served by the server in order to see all loaded extensions. This is the list:

```
array:45 [▼
  0 => "Core"
  1 => "bcmath"
  2 => "calendar"
  3 => "com_dotnet"
  4 => "ctype"
  5 => "date"
  6 => "filter"
  7 => "hash"
  8 => "iconv"
  9 => "json"
  10 => "SPL"
  11 => "odbc"
  12 => "pcre"
  13 => "Reflection"
  14 => "session"
  15 => "sockets"
  16 => "standard"
  17 => "mysqlnd"
  18 => "tokenizer"
  19 => "zip"
  20 => "zlib"
  21 => "libxml"
  22 => "dom"
  23 => "PDO"
  24 => "bz2"
  25 => "SimpleXML"
  26 => "soap"
  27 => "xml"
  28 => "wddx"
  29 => "xmlreader"
  30 => "xmlwriter"
  31 => "apache2handler"
  32 => "openssl"
  33 => "gd"
  34 => "gettext"
  35 => "mbstring"
  36 => "exif"
  37 => "mysqli"
  38 => "pdo_sqlite"
  39 => "sqlite3"
  40 => "curl"
  41 => "Phar"
  42 => "imagick"
  43 => "pdo_mysql"
  44 => "fileinfo"
]
```

In Laravel's database.php file, MySQL is set as default:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

I tried using composer update and composer dump-autoload too.

My database env variables are set correctly. I can interact with my database by inserting, deleting, updating and selecting, however, I cannot migrate for some reason:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lol
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I've read through all similar questions here and I'm out of options now.

Comment: Make sure that your php.ini is the same for both CLI and web/fpm. You can verify it by running `php -i` on the command line.

Comment: A lot of stuff got printed out when I ran php -i. I found this - Loaded configuration file => C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.3.7 and my server's php ini is loaded from C:\MAMP\conf\php7.3.7\php.ini. So they're indeed different but what am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 2):

you need install driver mysql for php. example for ubuntu `sudo apt install php-mysql`

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding a file called php.php under public folder with the content

```
<?php phpinfo ?>
```

and access it by the web URL not command line and make sure the mysql pdo extension enabled

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for in phpinfo()? Under PDO I get this - PDO drivers - sqlite, mysql. And under pdo_mysql I get this - Client API version mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $

Answer (score 0):

It means that for command line probably other `php.ini` is used that you updated. That's why when running site everything is working and when running PHP from console it doesn't.

You should run

```
php --ini
```

in command line to see what configuration files are used and make sure you have enabled in there MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have mysql pdo extension also check if DATABASE_TABLE exists which is running on your system otherwise you have to install it. that error is shown when you are trying to use database which is not on you machine.